# Is there any function which can use be instead of substr so that all data is accepted?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, substring

This is the code :

```
Substr(ap.invoice_num,9,6)='B    -'
AND rct.trx_number=
 Substr(ap.invoice_num, 0,8)
||'    -' 
|| Substr(ap.invoice_num,15,24)

AND rct.trx_number='69362695    -901645'
AND ap.invoice_num='69362695B    -901645'
```

But these values are not getting accepted:

```
AND rct.trx_number='15428234 -0001006048'
AND ap.invoice_num='15428234B    -0001006048'
```

Please suggest what changes to be made in substring function so that both the values I.e

```
AND rct.trx_number='69362695    -901645'
AND ap.invoice_num='69362695B    -901645'
```

and also this

```
AND rct.trx_number='15428234 -0001006048'
AND ap.invoice_num='15428234B    -0001006048'
```

Will get  accepted.??

Comment: Please add sample table data to your question.

Comment: use instr to find out where the "-" is and go from there

Comment: @OracleDev   , the values are still not getting accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ap (invoice_num) AS
SELECT '69362695B    -901645' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE rct (trx_number) AS
SELECT '69362695    -901645' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you need to change `15` to `14` as the substring with spaces you are matching in `trx_number` is shorter than `invoice_num`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ap CROSS JOIN rct
WHERE  SUBSTR(ap.invoice_num,9,6)='B    -'
AND    rct.trx_number = SUBSTR(rct.trx_number, 0,8) ||'    -'  || SUBSTR(rct.trx_number,14,6)
AND    rct.trx_number='69362695    -901645'
AND    ap.invoice_num='69362695B    -901645'
```

But it would be simpler just to use `SUBSTR` again:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ap CROSS JOIN rct
WHERE  SUBSTR(ap.invoice_num,9,6)='B    -'
AND    SUBSTR(rct.trx_number,9,5)='    -'
AND    rct.trx_number='69362695    -901645'
AND    ap.invoice_num='69362695B    -901645'
```

But the first two filters you are using won't match if the second two don't so it can be even simpler:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ap CROSS JOIN rct
WHERE  rct.trx_number='69362695    -901645'
AND    ap.invoice_num='69362695B    -901645'
```

As the substrings you are matching are present in the larger strings:

---

However, if you are intending to compare one column to the other (without the 9th character in `invoice_num`) then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   ap CROSS JOIN rct
WHERE  SUBSTR(ap.invoice_num,9,6)='B    -'
AND    rct.trx_number = SUBSTR(ap.invoice_num, 0,8) || SUBSTR(ap.invoice_num,10,11)
```

*Note: the `CROSS JOIN` should probably be an `INNER JOIN` but I am trying to replicate your `WHERE` condition.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9a1cffe914736fc8b147ec95ae230d70)*

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks as if you're about to compare `ap.invoice_num` and `rct.trx_number`, but *letters* and *spaces* bother you. If that's so, why wouldn't you "remove" them? Something like this (see what `JOIN` looks like):

```
SQL> with
  2  ap (invoice_num) as
  3    (SELECT '69362695B    -901645' FROM DUAL),
  4  rct (trx_number) as
  5    (SELECT '69362695    -901645' FROM DUAL)
  6  select *
  7  from ap a join rct r on regexp_replace(a.invoice_num, '[[:alpha:] ]') =
  8                          regexp_replace(r.trx_number , '[[:alpha:] ]');

INVOICE_NUM          TRX_NUMBER
-------------------- -------------------
69362695B    -901645 69362695    -901645

SQL>
```

---

Saying that the following values aren't "accepted":

```
AND rct.trx_number='69396083    -0000881362'
AND ap.invoice_num='15428234B    -00001006048'
```

Well, why would they be? They've got **nothing** in common.